# How to revive this dead 3.7 V Li-ion pouch battery?

Tags: batteries, lithium-ion, tp4056

I made this Bluetooth speaker and I was happy it's working.

I left it running and somehow the battery is dead. Battery voltage is now ZERO

Any attempt to charge it using TP4056 board is not bringing it back to life.

So the battery is totally useless?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems to have a protection board to shut down and disconnect the battery from circuit to prevent discharging the battery below damaging and dangerous level.

So the protection worked and battery worked as per the specifications.

It may be unusable now, but also not dangerous.

Usually it is possible to charge such batteries though, by trickle charging them. TP4056 should trickle charge a battery when it is below safe charging voltage, but if the battery is still connected to other circuitry that loads the trickle charge voltage to zero, it can't trickle charge it.

Disconnect the battery from load and only connect it to TP4056 charger.

That should be the default operation anyway, as the TP4056 cannot detect how much current goes into battery and how much goes into load instead of battery, so it will fail to detect when the battery is full if battery is connected to a load, and this will overcharge the battery, possibly degrading and damaging it, but again it seems that the battery is protected so there won't be gross overcharge.

If it still does not trickle charge the battery, it might need resetting the tripper overdischarge protection somehow, but it requires unwrapping the pack protection board and trying to reverse-engineer which chip is used and how to reset the tripped protection.

It might be safer to buy a new battery and not cause the overdischarge protection to trip.

Comment: Okay step one, I disconnect the load and the battery is giving ZERO volts. No movement on multimeter at all. 

I'll now connect a separate TP4056 to see if it does the trickle charging. 

I'll be reporting back shortly.

Comment: Charging with same TP4056 charging board without a load worked. The battery is back to life. Any idea why it died? 

Is it okay to to use the load while charging using TP4056?

Comment: @basitj Something discharged the battery and the underdischarge protection kicked in. Of course it is **not** possible to use load while charging, I already explained the TP4056 cannot detect when battery becomes full and it overcharges the battery which will degrade and damage the cell, overcharging protection just protects cell from one-off catastrophical failure.

Answer (score 0):

Get a meter. Measure the voltage directly at the cell (not at the battery terminals).

If the voltage of the cell is at least 2.8 V, the battery may be salvageable.

If lower, do not attempt to circumvent the BMS and recharge the cell. Doing so may damage the cell such that it may blow up.

Comment: I don't know what do you mean by "directly at the cell" ? Do I unwrap the yellow seal and see what's inside? I've never done that

I've disconnected everything now and the battery only on terminal is giving ZERO voltage. No movement on multimeter whatsoever.

Comment: "what do you mean by "directly at the cell"?" It means the two flat tabs coming out of the rectangular cell. (Not the red and black wires coming out of the protector PCB.) Yes, you have to remove the yellow tape to get to them. Or at least poke through the tape.